# Not able to use socket io in heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, socket.io, port

I am new to Heroku and I am trying to deploy NodeJS application that is using socket.io to listen.
I am able to deploy that to local and its working fine. but when running the same in Heroku it is not responding.

Is there any specific port that we need to assign for socket io in Heroku?
I can't use process.env.PORT as I am using that for app server port.

Any Idea to solve this issue? or do we need to enable some config to use socket io?

I think we need 2 ports, one for normal express server and other for socket io. How to get the 2nd one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to open more ports than 80 to the public. But WebSockets and especially socket.io should work on heroku.

Have you read these articles:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-websockets

socket.io -> https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-websockets#option-2-socket-io

http://robdodson.me/deploying-your-first-node-dot-js-and-socket-dot-io-app-to-heroku/

It's not a problem to have the websockets on port 80 because the protocol is `ws:// (wss://)` and it works with `http:// (https://)` side by side.

Comment: Thanks, Simon. just wanted to check if it is a good approach to use the same port for WebSocket, because it was working fine for me.

Comment: Can you please check this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34498819/socket-io-works-with-localhost-but-not-on-heroku-server